# AngularFireFunction Directly Call Cloud Function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an Angular website and I am trying to integrate cloud functions as Expressjs. Only cloud functions work fine. When I go to http://localhost:5001/project_id/us-central1/app, I can see the console output. But with angular, it doesn't work.

Here is the output when trying with angular:

`hosting: 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2020:18:57:01 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 4286 "http://localhost:5000/payment" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"`

functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Hello");
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

app.module.ts:

```
...
providers: [UserService, AngularFireAuthGuard,
    { provide: ORIGIN,useValue: 'http://localhost:5001' },
    { provide: REGION, useValue: 'us-central1' }],
...
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/user",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

payment.component.ts (where I trying to call cloud functions):

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private fns: AngularFireFunctions) {
    const callable = fns.httpsCallable('app');
    var data = callable({ name: 'some-data' });
    data.subscribe(async res => {
      console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

Comment: You haven't exported anything from index.js.  I suggest reviewing the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps

Comment: @DougStevenson I exported but I missed put that part, sorry. I edited the first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client app is trying to invoke a callable function, but your actual function is a HTTP function backed by an express app.  This combination isn't going to work.  If you want to use a callable function, you will have to follow the instructions in the [documentation for callables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and declare an `onCall` function, not `onRequest`.  `onRequest` is for normal HTTP invocations.  From that documentation, note:

> It's important to keep in mind that HTTPS callable functions are
> similar but not identical to HTTP functions. To use HTTPS callable
> functions you must use the client SDK for your platform together with
> the functions.https backend API (or implement the protocol). Callables
> have these key difference from HTTP functions:

Alternatively, if you really do want to use an express app on the backend, you won't be able to invoke it using the Firebase Functions client SDK.  Use a normal HTTP client library for that.

Comment: Thank you. I am new for that. I change as `onCall` but it is the same. What should I do?

Comment: Read and follow the link to the documentation I provided in the answer.